# ¿Cómo rotar un rigidBody en Bullet?

Tags: c++, motor-de-juego, ogre

Tengo un cuerpo rígido, quiero que dicho cuerpo se desplace siempre hacia adelante, pero cuando choque con otra forma de colisión rote y se siga desplazando hacia adelante.

He logrado que rote, pero no se desplaza, parece que **no rota en local**, por lo que he eliminado todo el código.

Lo desplazo con:

```
->setLinearVelocity(direction * velocity);
```

Este es el code de mi último intento:

```
btTransform btT;
_rigidBody->getBulletRigidBody()->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(btT);
//------------------NEW ROTATION-------------------
btQuaternion btNewQuaternion;
btNewQuaternion.setEuler(btScalar(10), btScalar(0), btScalar(0));
//-------------------------------------------------
btT.setRotation(btNewQuaternion);
_rigidBody->getBulletRigidBody()->setCenterOfMassTransform(btT);
```

El problema es que **no suma 10**, sino que lo setea fijo, yo necesito que se le sume eso a la rotación actual.

Comment: Tienes un objeto que tiene una velocidad y una rotacion, cuando colisione quieres que a la rotación que ya tiene se le agregue un yaw de +10 ?

Comment: tiene una posición y rotación inicial, mi idea es que se desplace (caminar) y si el rayo detecta que a pocos centímetros hay otro objeto, gire 10 grados, así sucesivamente hasta que no haya un objeto al frente, una vez que no haya otro objeto, se continué desplazando. He logrado lo anterior pero no se desplaza mas :(